# VB.NET tutorial for username/password check using database

Tags: vb.net, authentication

Where is a good VB.NET tutorial where I can have a username box and a password box and it checks in the database if it's there and if it is then another form will show?

Comment: winforms, wpf, silverlight, asp.net webforms, asp.net mvc? Each of those has subtly different system, and hence a different tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

Look here:

**[Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)**

There are a couple things you should know before you get started:

1. Never, NEVER, **NEVER** store a plain-text password anywhere in your database. For that matter, don't even store an *encrypted* password in your database. Instead, you store a *hashed* password, using a cryptographic hashing algorithm (md5 isn't good enough). When someone wants to log in, you hash the attempted password and compare the hashes. Even this is the simplified version.
2. You *never* want to implement security-related code yourself. Always rely as much as possible on the tools provided to you by your platform. The reason for this is that it's just so easy to write something seems to work — maybe even passes a whole slew of unit tests — but is still subtly flawed such that a year after going live with it you'll find out you were hacked six months ago. You don't want to be in that situation.